# play video on StageVideo with starling

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d, starling-framework

i work on as3 mobile project , iam using starling as Framework , how i can added a video on starling using stage video , not video player .
stage video option is a lot better for performance .
any one to advice me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answer :
 add your stage video class inside starling display object as overlay :

```
Starling.current.nativeOverlay.addChild(stageVideoPlayer)
```

Comment: Can you please post a full code. Because I can't add the stageVideo instance to Starling.current.nativeOverlay. I won't compile and won't let me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi sameer I couldn't understand you need to add a device's camera recording a video  or need to add any video file on stage using starling? Give detailed explanation.

Comment: hello , no , i build a as3 mobile project using starling and feathers UI , so i need to play video on stage video so starling doesn't support stage video , i add a flash class to play video via stage video , here i need to add flash class inside starling class , but i don't know how .. i ask and found this code above will add flash class inside starling class as overlay .

Comment: Create a separate class which contains core Flash display Objects. And add that video file on Starling.current.nativeStage.addChild(video); This will add on top of starling stage. Whenever you want's to remove you can remove also. I hope this is what you need.